# can I use RxJava to write ejb apps to be deployed in WebSphere 8

Tags: rx-java, websphere-8

EJB 3.x specs say, not to create and manage threads, can I use RxJava without me explicitly doing that.

notes: What I am worried about is, `do RxJava implicitly create and manage threads even for simple tasks?` if yes, then it becomes in-eligible to be used for EJB 3.1 development.

I am using WebSphere 8.5.5.5, java 7, EJB 3.1

Comment: With Java EE7 (EJB 3.2), there is a safe way to do thready things using Concurrency Utilities (JSR-236). We have a sample that shows this integration: https://github.com/WASdev/sample.rxjava. I mention it only because you opened the question with 3.x. ;) 

For EJB 3.1 with WebSphere 8.5.5.5, do you mean Liberty or traditional?

Comment: sorry, I should have been explicit. I am talking about EJB 3.1 WAS8.5.5 Traditional Full Profile

Answer (score 2):

In RxJava there are two operations, "subscribeOn" (http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html)  and "observeOn" (http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/observeon.html) that allow you to specify a Scheduler (ie: JEE Executor) that will be used to create a new thread to use when it's carrying out the subscribe / observe routines.

By default though, if you don't specify any schedulers, then it would run all in the same thread, so you're ok.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.